# How to do order in grouping(aggregation) in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have SQL query like this:

```
select count(id) as ct, city from table group by city order by ct desc
```

How can I perform this query in Couchbase? 
I have map function like This:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.city!==null) {
  emit(doc.city,1)
    }
}
```

and reduce:

```
_count
```

my query url is like this: 
`_view/q7?group_level=1&descending=true`
but it it sort only for key not for value.

Comment: might be duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292609/how-do-you-sort-results-of-a-view-by-value-in-the-in-couchbase